# Angular 6 PWA / SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, service

I have migrated an angular application from 5 to 6. before service worker was working properly,  but when I am built production build, ng build -- prod, 
it is giving below error...

```
Error:-  
Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at MapSubscriber.host.exists.pipe.operators_1.map.content [as project] (F:\dpm_doctor_angular5\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\utilities\service-worker\index.js:90:41).
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed encoding of **ngsw-config.json** from **UTF** to **ANSI** and it worked.